# Evaluate whether an expression is tautology or not

Tags: algorithm, boolean, boolean-expression

I am looking for an algorithm to find whether an expression is a tautology or not ? I tried using truth table (brute force) but this is not feasible in my case.

Comment: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc/spr10/slides/pnp3.pdf

Comment: So what's your question? Have you done any research? What kind of expressions are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formula is a tautology if and only if its negation is satisfiable. Satisfiability is an NP-hard problem, but there are [many solvers](http://www.satcompetition.org/) that do better than brute force.